# Error "Invalid call to qualifier on unresolved object"

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I can share some part of the code, unfortunately I have a strange error for some reason

```
------
WITH parent_A AS (
        SELECT 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(specialty))+2 AS id
            , 2                                             AS parent_id
            , 'A'                                           AS type
            , specialty                                     AS name 
            , '0'                                           AS is_root  
            , '0'                                           AS is_leaf
            , NULL                                          AS dept_id 
            , CONCAT('A_' , specialty)                      AS label  
        FROM  (  SELECT DISTINCT specialty FROM tmp ORDER BY 1) as w 
), child_A AS (
    SELECT
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(t.dept_name))+(SELECT MAX(id) FROM parent_star_db) AS id
          , r.id                                                               AS parent_id
          , 'A'                                                                AS type
          , t.dept_name                                                        AS name 
          , '0'                                                                AS is_root  
          , '1'                                                                AS is_leaf  
          , t.data_c                                                           AS dept_id  
          , CONCAT('A_' , t.data_c , '_' , t.dept_name)                        AS label
    FROM tmp as t
    JOIN parent_A as r ON t.specialty = r.name
)


SELECT  * FROM parent_A
UNION ALL
SELECT  * FROM child_A
```

i keep getting this error:

`Error Invalid call to qualifier on unresolved object:  tree '`

it works if i take the parent id comment in child_A and put another value
( 0 as parent_id )

Comment: Could you please provide your sample data and expected results?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I found the problem but I don't have a solution

There is no information about parent_A, but I have child_A. I'm using + max(id) . not working coalesce(....)